# Which context has the verb "constitute" been used in here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this sentence in a book named "Word Power Made Easy":

> It is only the few who are so **constituted** that lack of learning becomes a nuisance.

I am not able to figure out which context the verb "constitute" has been used in here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In this context, "constitute" has the meaning od "built", "designed".

> It is only the few **who's minds are made in such way** that the lack of learning becomes a nuisance.

Comment: Yes. It's a very old-fashioned use. It survives more as the noun: one of the meanings of _constitution_ is "a person's general standard of health, especially as it affects their resilience".